# Animar o texto de um textView de forma a ser exibido progressivamente?

Tags: android, animação, textview

Gostaria que o texto da textView presente na minha activity não fosse exibido todo de uma vez, mas aos poucos, algo como uma transição do Power Point.

Um exemplo do que quero fazer exatamente seria textos de diálogos dos jogos de pokémon de GBA [VEJA A PARTIR DE 1:33](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWsxhzTpndI) não necessariamente um caractere de cada vez como exibido no vídeo, mas uma palavra de cada vez até o fim do texto.

Gostaria de saber se tem como limitar o tempo total da escrita do texto, de modo que se o limite imposto for ultrapassado, o restante do texto seja todo escrito instantaneamente (**para textos muito longos**).

**activity:**

```js
package genesysgeneration.font;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(android.R.layout.activity_list_item);

        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText("Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.");

    }
}
```

**xml:**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit:

Tentei o sugerido por **@Mr_Anderson**, porém não obtive sucesso.

Vária linhas apresentaram erros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

MainActivity:

```js
package genesysgeneration.pokemaos;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TypeWriter t = (TypeWriter)findViewById(R.id.meuTxt);
        t.setCharacterDelay(100);
        t.animateText("Olha só");

    }
}
```

Class:

```js
package genesysgeneration.pokemaos;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.logging.Handler;

public class TypeWriter extends TextView {

    private CharSequence mText;
    private int mIndex;
    private long mDelay = 500;

    public TypeWriter(Context context){

        super(context);

    }

    public TypeWriter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){

        super(context, attrs);

    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable characterAdder = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setText(mText.subSequence(0, mIndex++));
            if (mIndex<=mText.length()){

                mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay);

            }
        }
    };

    public void animateText(CharSequence text){

        mText=text;
        mIndex=0;

        setText("");
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(characterAdder);
        mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay);

    }

    public void setCharacterDelay(long millis){

        mDelay=millis;

    }

}
```

xml:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="genesysgeneration.pokemaos.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.Pokemaos.view.custom.TypeWriter

        android:id="@+id/meuTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Você pode usar essa resposta como fonte: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700374/android-character-by-character-display-text-animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você vai criar uma classe que é uma view customizada

```
public class Typewriter extends TextView {

    private CharSequence mText;
    private int mIndex;
    private long mDelay = 500; //Default 500ms delay


    public Typewriter(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Typewriter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable characterAdder = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setText(mText.subSequence(0, mIndex++));
            if(mIndex <= mText.length()) {
                mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay);
            }
        }
    };

    public void animateText(CharSequence text) {
        mText = text;
        mIndex = 0;

        setText("");
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(characterAdder);
        mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay);
    }

    public void setCharacterDelay(long millis) {
        mDelay = millis;
    }
}
```

Depois usa ela no xml activity_main **(Editado)**

```
<genesysgeneration.pokemaos.Typewriter
        android:id="@+id/meuTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Depois é só instanciar na MainActivity

```
Typewriter t = (Typewriter) findViewById(R.id.meuTxt);
t.setCharacterDelay(100);
t.animateText("Olha só que legal");
```

Comment: no xml da mainActivity?

Comment: No seu código, você importou o Handler errado. Use o import correto: import android.os.Handler;
Na hora de usar o widget no xml activity_main, só digite <Typewriter e dê um enter que o Android studio vai auto-completar com o pacote na qual você criou sua classe Typewriter, que é o genesysgeneration.pokemaos

Comment: Editei o xml da resposta...

Comment: sussa, agora a seguinte linha continua acusando erro `public class TypeWriter extends TextView {` mais especificamente o extends TextView.

Comment: Bem, mesmo acusando esse erro, roda tudo de boa, mas não estou conseguindo fazer com que minha textView exiba esse animated text, além disso tudo o mais que tem na activity some!!!

Comment: Use um texto maior... Talvez a animação de um texto curto demais acabe rápido demais e não dê a impressão de estar sendo "teclado" aos poucos.

Comment: nn, a impressão de que esta sendo digitado acontece, o problema é que todo o restante da activity some

Comment: Pode postar o xml do da sua activity?
Você se certificou de ajustar o layout_width e o layout_height de acordo com a sua necessidade? Certificou-se de que ambos não estão com match_parent?

Comment: Tudo certo, único problema continua sendo somente o erro que é acusado na seguinte linha: `public class Typewriter extends TextView {`, de qualquer forma ele não impede a aplicação de ser executada corretamente

Comment: Certo. Aqui também ocorre. Você pode dar alt+enter que o Android studio vai pedir para que você estenda de AppCompatTextView ao invés de um TextView. Pelo que li, ele pede isso para que seu textView, se executado em APIs baixas, suporte métodos que somente funcionariam em APIs mais recentes...

Comment: Hey e como fazer para executar uma ação assim que ele for finalizado?

Answer (score 3):

Recorrendo ao [Property animation system](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/package-summary.html)(Sistema de animação de propriedades) do SDK é possível conseguir o efeito que pretende.

Esta abordagem permite ter de "borla" todas as funcionalidades do sistema de animação como *pause/resume*, *reverse*, *repeat*, *animator listener* e *update listener*.

Escreva um *wrapper* sobre um [ValueAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html) em conjunto com um [TimeInterpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TimeInterpolator.html) e dois [TypeEvaluator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TypeEvaluator.html).

O TimeInterpolator é usado para calcular o número de letras ou número de palavras que o texto deve ter num determinado instante da animação.

Os ValueAnimator usam o valor calculado pelo TimeInterpolator para determinar a parte do texto que deve ser apresentada nesse instante da animação.

**TextViewAnimator.java**

```
public class TextViewAnimator {

    private TextValueAnimator textValueAnimator;

    public static TextViewAnimator perLetter(TextView textView){

        int steps = textView.getText().length();
        TextViewAnimator textViewAnimator =
                new TextViewAnimator(textView,
                                     new TextEvaluatorPerLetter(),
                                     new TextInterpolator(steps));
        return textViewAnimator;
    }

    public static TextViewAnimator perWord(TextView textView){

        int steps = textView.getText().toString().split(" ").length;

        TextViewAnimator textViewAnimator =
                new TextViewAnimator(textView,
                                     new TextEvaluatorPerWord(),
                                     new TextInterpolator(steps));
        return textViewAnimator;
    }

    public TextViewAnimator(TextView textView,
                            TypeEvaluator typeEvaluator,
                            TextInterpolator textInterpolator){

        this.textValueAnimator = new TextValueAnimator(textView, textView.getText().toString());
        textValueAnimator.setEvaluator(typeEvaluator);
        textValueAnimator.setInterpolator(textInterpolator);
    }

    private static class TextValueAnimator extends ValueAnimator implements ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {

        private WeakReference<TextView> weakTextView;

        public TextValueAnimator(TextView textView, String text) {

            weakTextView = new WeakReference<>(textView);
            setObjectValues(text);
            addUpdateListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            String text = (String) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            TextView textView = weakTextView.get();
            if(textView != null) {
                textView.setText(text);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class TextEvaluatorPerLetter implements TypeEvaluator {

        @Override
        public Object evaluate(float fraction, Object startValue, Object endValue) {
            int step = (int) fraction;
            return ((String) endValue).substring(0, step);
        }
    }

    private static class TextEvaluatorPerWord implements TypeEvaluator {

        private String[] words;
        @Override
        public Object evaluate(float fraction, Object startValue, Object endValue) {

            int step = (int) fraction;
            if(words == null){
                words = ((String) endValue).split(" ");
            }
            String textAtStep = "";
            for (int i = 1; i <= step; i++) {
                textAtStep += words[i-1] + " ";
            }

            return textAtStep;
        }
    }

    private static class TextInterpolator implements TimeInterpolator {

        private int steps;
        public TextInterpolator(int steps) {

            this.steps = steps;
        }
        @Override
        public float getInterpolation(float input) {
            return input * steps;
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        textValueAnimator.start();
    }
    public void cancel(){
        textValueAnimator.cancel();
    }
    public void end(){
        textValueAnimator.end();
    }

    @RequiresApi(19)  
    public void pause(){
        textValueAnimator.pause();
    }
    @RequiresApi(19)
    public void resume(){
        textValueAnimator.resume();
    }
    @RequiresApi(19)
    public boolean isStarted(){
        return textValueAnimator.isStarted();
    }
    @RequiresApi(19)
    public float getAnimatedFraction(){
        return textValueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();
    }
    public void setRepeatCount(int value){
        textValueAnimator.setRepeatCount(value);
    }
    public void setRepeatMode(int repeatMode){
        textValueAnimator.setRepeatMode(repeatMode);
    }
    public void setDuration(long duration){
        textValueAnimator.setDuration(duration);
    }
    public void setStartDelay(long startDelay){
        textValueAnimator.setStartDelay(startDelay);
    }
    public void addUpdateListener(ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener listener){
        textValueAnimator.addUpdateListener(listener);
    }
    public void removeUpdateListener(ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener listener){
        textValueAnimator.removeUpdateListener(listener);
    }
    public boolean isRunning(){
        return textValueAnimator.isRunning();
    }
    public void addListener(Animator.AnimatorListener listener){
        textValueAnimator.addListener(listener);
    }
    public void removeListener(Animator.AnimatorListener listener){
        textValueAnimator.removeListener(listener);
    }
}
```

A classe disponibiliza dois *factory methods*:

- `TextViewAnimator.perLetter()`.
  Retorna um TextViewAnimator que anima o texto, previamente atribuído ao TextView, letra por letra.
- `TextViewAnimator.perWord()`.
  Retorna um TextViewAnimator que anima o texto, previamente atribuído ao TextView, palavra por palavra.

A escolha de um "wrapper" para a implementação, em vez de herança, deve-se à necessidade de "esconder" alguns dos métodos públicos da classe ValueAnimator.

Exemplo de utilização de animação letra por letra:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    Button button;
    TextViewAnimator textViewAnimator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

        textViewAnimator = TextViewAnimator.perLetter(textView);
        textViewAnimator.setDuration(5000);
        textViewAnimator.setRepeatCount(2);
        textViewAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textViewAnimator.start();
            }
        });    
    }
}
```

O layout da Activity(*activity_main.xml*) deverá ter um Button e um TextView com id's `"@+id/button"`e `"@+id/text1"` respectivamente.

**Notas:**
 - Requer `minSdkVersion 11`.
 - Alguns métodos requerem `minSdkVersion 19`.

Comment: Esqueceu de comentar sobre a versão mínima do SDK, no qual funcionará essa classe.

Comment: Olha o que encontrei: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#pause()

Outra coisa: Observei que o texto é escrito até o fim e depois volta apagando novamente até completar o tempo máximo definido. ps.: só estou ajudando na qualidade da resposta.

Comment: @AckLay Esse comportamento foi introduzido propositadamente no  exemplo da resposta para demonstrar uma da várias possibilidades de animação. Ele é obtido pelas linhas `textViewAnimator.setRepeatCount(2);` e `textViewAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);`. Elimine-as para o texto ser escrito uma só vez. Não entendi o que quer com a referência em relação ao `pause()`.

Comment: @AckLay Descobri porque falou no `onPause()`. Você podia ter dito logo que necessitava da API19 :)

Comment: Ué, te enviei o link focando exatamente o método `pause()`. Achei que você iria olhar no canto direito. Desculpa! xD

Answer (score 2):

Apesar do Ramaral ter dado uma resposta válida, pensei de uma outra forma no qual funciona para qualquer versão do Android.

Basicamente uso o `Runnanble` com um `delay` concatenando letra por letra ou palavra por palavra.

- `animPerLetter()`: letra por letra
- `animPerWord()`: palavra por palavra

**MainActivity:**

```
TextAnimatedView textAnimatedView = (TextAnimatedView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
textAnimatedView.setCharacterDelay(150);
textAnimatedView.animPerWord("Desta forma vai funcionar como esperado");
```

No **XML** você usa desta forma abaixo:

```
<seu.pacote.TextAnimatedView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Veja abaixo como ficou a classe `TextAnimatedView`:

```
public class TextAnimatedView extends TextView {

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    private CharSequence text;
    private String[] arr;
    private int i;
    private long delay = 450;

    public TextAnimatedView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TextAnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setText(text.subSequence(0, i++));
            if (i <= text.length()) {
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
            }
        }
    };

    public void animPerLetter(CharSequence text) {
        this.text = text;
        i = 0;

        setText("");
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
    }

    private Runnable runnablePerWord = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            stringBuilder.append(arr[i++]).append(" ");
            setText(stringBuilder.toString());
            if (i < arr.length) {
                handler.postDelayed(runnablePerWord, delay);
            }
        }
    };

    public void animPerWord(CharSequence text) {
        this.text = text;
        i = 0;

        setText("");
        arr = text.toString().split(" ");
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnablePerWord);
        handler.postDelayed(runnablePerWord, delay);
    }

    public void setCharacterDelay(long delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }
}
```

#### Um **GIF** vale mais que mil imagens.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa é idêntica à resposta do Mr_Anderson.

Comment: @ramaral quando tem-se complementação de alguma outra resposta, você edita a resposta do usuário ou você cria uma nova? Foquei na parte que o AP pergunta "[...]não necessariamente um caractere de cada vez como exibido no vídeo, mas uma palavra de cada vez até o fim do texto.[...]". Na minha opinião, digo na minha opinião, sua resposta não atende esse requisito da pergunta.

Comment: A sua resposta é válida. Não quis dizer que não devia responder, foi apenas uma observação. O exemplo que ele dá é letra a letra, apenas refere que não precisa de ser assim, que pode ser palavra a palavra.

Comment: @ramaral importante é ajudar, aprendendo. =)