# Como reproduzir um som somente enquanto um TextView animado está sendo reproduzido?

Tags: android, animação, textview

O som que estou utilizando é de um teclado sendo teclado e foi retirado desse vídeo => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcNlc0zTMuU

**Duração => 2.577 segundos**

Adicionei-o ao à pasta RAW do projeto em questão e gostaria de saber **como fazer para que esse som fosse reproduzido e se repetisse enquanto o TextView animado não fosse completamente reproduzido**.

TypeWriter:

```js
package genesysgeneration.animatedtext;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TypeWriter extends TextView {

    private CharSequence mText;
    private int mIndex;
    private long mDelay = 1;

    public TypeWriter(Context context){

        super(context);

    }

    public TypeWriter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){

        super(context, attrs);

    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable characterAdder = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setText(mText.subSequence(0, mIndex++));
            if (mIndex<=mText.length()){

                mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay);

            }
        }
    };

    public void animatedText(CharSequence text){

        mText=text;
        mIndex=0;

        setText("");
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(characterAdder);
        mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay);

    }

    public void setCharacterDelay(long millis){

        mDelay=millis;

    }

}
```

MainActivity:

```js
package genesysgeneration.animatedtext;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MediaPlayer teclado_02 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.teclado_02);

        TypeWriter tv = (TypeWriter)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setCharacterDelay(1);
        tv.animatedText("(nova execução) Pirulito ki bate bate, pirulito ki jah bateu!!!\n(nova execução) Pirulito ki bate bate, pirulito ki jah bateu!!!\n(nova execução) Pirulito ki bate bate, pirulito ki jah bateu!!!\n(nova execução) Pirulito ki bate bate, pirulito ki jah bateu!!!\n(nova execução) Pirulito ki bate bate, pirulito ki jah bateu!!!\n(nova execução) Pirulito ki bate bate, pirulito ki jah bateu!!!\n(nova execução) Pirulito ki bate bate, pirulito ki jah bateu!!!\n");

    }
}
```

XML (MainActivity):

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="genesysgeneration.animatedtext.MainActivity">

    <genesysgeneration.animatedtext.TypeWriter
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Se estivesse a usar o código desta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193247/2541) bastaria adicionar um AnimatorListener e no método `onAnimationStart()` iniciar o som e no método `onAnimationEnd()` parar o som.

Comment: @ramaral preciso que me ajude, o código que utilizei não é totalmente igual ao da sua resposta, pode vir de chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56769/animation-on-textview

Comment: Gostaria de saber em que parte do código exatamente (coloquei no chat) eu preciso inserir o som

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola, antes de chamar a animação tente

```
teclado_02.setLooping(true);
teclado_02.start();
```

depois de acordo com os ajustes [desta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204815/como-fazer-para-que-um-button-se-torne-vis%C3%ADvel-somente-depois-que-um-textview-an/204850?noredirect=1#comment419968_204850) pergunta
no mesmo bloco onde deixamos o botao visivel voce pode parar o som com `teclado_02.stop();`

Porem não é a melhor solução, recomendo melhorar seu codigo com o link do

> Se estivesse a usar o código [desta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193247/2541) resposta bastaria adicionar um AnimatorListener e no método onAnimationStart() iniciar o som e no método onAnimationEnd() parar o som.