# Como fazer para que um Button se torne visível somente depois que um TextView animado tenha sido completamente escrito?

Tags: android, textview

No **protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)** da **MainActivity** eu seto o button para que o mesmo seja invisível e também para que não ocupe espaço com o seguinte código: `button.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

**MainActivity**:

```js
package genesysgeneration.stackx;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        TypeWriter textView=(TypeWriter)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setCharacterDelay(1);
        textView.animatedText("lansdfçaksjfçkajsçfljkasçlfkaçslkgçlaksgçlaksglçakçlgmnasçkdnbklanslkjbnlkasnbklanslkbnalksbnlaksn");

    }
}
```

Utilizo a seguinte classe (TypeWriter) para que o TextView seja escrito aos poucos (daí o termo TextView animado que utilizei).

**TypeWriter**:

```js
public class TypeWriter extends TextView{

    private CharSequence mText;
    private int mIndex;
    private long mDelay = 1;

    public TypeWriter(Context context){

        super(context);

    }

    public TypeWriter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){

        super(context, attrs);

    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable characterAdder = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setText(mText.subSequence(0, mIndex++));
            if (mIndex<=mText.length()){

                mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay);

            }
        }
    };

    public void animatedText(CharSequence text){

        mText=text;
        mIndex=0;

        setText("");
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(characterAdder);
        mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay);

    }

    public void setCharacterDelay(long millis){

        mDelay=millis;

    }

}
```

**XML**:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="genesysgeneration.stackx.MainActivity">

    <genesysgeneration.stackx.TypeWriter
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Gostaria que somente depois de todo o texto ter sido escrito, o Button se tornasse visível**.

Não faço ideia de onde colocar no código para que o button se torne novamente visível após o TextView ter sido totalmente escrito, mas creio que seja na **MainActivity**.

Já pensei em contar a quantidade de caracteres para depois comparar, mas não deu certo (pelo menos não da forma que tentei).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ola,

Não sei se esta é a melhor forma de fazer....

Crie um atributo de classe do tipo Runnable responsavel pela acao ao terminar a animação

```
private Runnable postAction = null;
```

Depois crie um setter pára ele

```
public void setPostAction(Runnable postAction) {
    this.postAction = postAction;
}
```

Então edite o metodo run do characterAdder para:

```
public void run() {
            setText(mText.subSequence(0, mIndex++));
            if (mIndex<=mText.length()){

                mHandler.postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay);

            }else{
                if (postAction != null){
                    postAction.run();
                }
            }
        }
```

por fim edite no mainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        TypeWriter textView=(TypeWriter)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setCharacterDelay(1);
        textView.setPostAction(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        textView.animatedText("lansdfçaksjfçkajsçfljkasçlfkaçslkgçlaksgçlaksglçakçlgmnasçkdnbklanslkjbnlkasnbklanslkbnalksbnlaksn");
    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! Tenho uma questão que envolve essa mesma classe (TypeWriter), porém essa é em relação a um aúdio que eu gostaria que fosse tocado enquanto o TextView estivesse sendo executado, acha que poderia me dar um help nela também?

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194084/como-reproduzir-um-som-somente-enquanto-um-textview-animado-est%c3%a1-sendo-reproduzi